# How to delay jquery hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu with categories, 
when I hover on a category a drop down show up 
(I have already delayed the drop down to show up after 600 MS),

I want to know how to delay the hover event on the category too for 600 MS,
What is the best way and easiest way to achieve this using jquery?

```
jQuery('div.dropdown').hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.services-shortcut').addClass('active');
    jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(600).fadeIn(0);
}, function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.services-shortcut').removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(600).fadeOut(0);
});
```

I have made a bootply here http://www.bootply.com/lXioubaMre

Comment: [This plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) may be best for you. Look at demos below.

Comment: Is there any easy way to achieve it without a plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a basic CSS transition

```
.services-shortcut {
    transition: all 0s .6s;
}
```

that runs immediately after a `600ms` delay

Example: http://www.bootply.com/xppQzbvQ3P

If you choose to do this effect absolutely in javascript (but I wouldn't do it, just to keep off style from javascript) then apply the `active` class after a `600ms` timeout, e.g.

```
jQuery('div.dropdown').hover(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.find('.services-shortcut').addClass('active');
    }, 600);
    $this.find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(600).fadeIn(0);
}, ...
```

If you use this approach then you should also clear the interval `onmouseout`

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly, but I'm worried about browser support for css3. Is there a way to make the same result using jquery?

Comment: CSS transitions are widely supported (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) and on `IE<10` the hover effect just works (graceful degradation). I wouldn't suggest to use javascript code for this kind of effect. If you want to do it in javascript just run a setTimeout before applying the `active` class

Comment: Thanks for the info, the css3 method worked fine but the jquery one didnt work.

Comment: I went with the css3 method

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) jQuery plugin, which triggers functions based on client mouse movement. In your case the script would be simple, you can take a look at [this Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/h3Ov1a4f4s):

```
function showMenu(e) {
    jQuery(this).find('.services-shortcut').addClass('active');
    jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').show();
};
function hideMenu(e) {
    jQuery(this).find('.services-shortcut').removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').hide();
};

$("div.dropdown").hoverIntent({
    over: showMenu,
    out: hideMenu,
    sensitivity: 3,
    timeout: 800
});

$(".dropdown-menu a").hoverIntent({
    over: function(){
        $(this).addClass('active')
    },
    out: function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active')
    },
    sensitivity: 3
});
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly, but i went with the css3 method after all.

Comment: I also think css is better for your menu. This plugin above is for special cases.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [$.hoverDelay() plugin](http://ronency.github.io/hoverDelay/) that does exactly that. It lets you configure the delay(s) for the 'in' and 'out' events like so:

```
$('div.dropdown').hoverDelay({
  delayIn: 200,
  delayOut:700,
  handlerIn: function($element){
    $element.css({backgroundColor: 'red'});  
  },
  handlerOut: function($element){
    $element.css({backgroundColor: 'auto'});  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [**jQuery.delay() method**](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) :

```js
jQuery('div.dropdown').hover(function() {
  alert("Action delayed");
    jQuery(this).find('.services-shortcut').addClass('active');
    jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(600).fadeIn(0);
}, function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.services-shortcut').removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(600).fadeOut(0);
}).delay(600);
```

```css
.dropdown{
  background-color:red;
]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  aaaa
  </div>
```

That will wait for `600ms` before executing your action, that's all you need.

Comment: using this approach event will be fired all the time but after waiting for the given time , using other way events will not be fired unit the desired time of hover is reached .